# TList > will not return from "delete src" where src is pointer to struct

Tags: c++builder

My Environment:

```
C++ Builder XE4
```

I am trying to use TList for storing struct data. Following is my sample code.

```
struct data_t {
    int key;
    String name;
};
TList *list;


void __fastcall TForm1::addButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // add records
    list = new TList();
    data_t *dataArray = new data_t[2];

    dataArray[0].key = 31415;
    dataArray[0].name = L"pi";
    list->Add(&dataArray[0]);

    dataArray[1].key = 27182;
    dataArray[1].name = L"napier";
    list->Add(&dataArray[1]);

    ShowMessage(L"added");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::showButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // get records
    data_t *src;
    for(int idx=0; idx < list->Count; idx++) {
        src = (data_t*)list->Items[idx];
        String msg;
        msg = L"key:" + IntToStr(src->key) + " name:" + src->name;
        ShowMessage(msg);
    }

    // free
    for(int idx=0; idx < list->Count; idx++) {
        src = (data_t*)list->Items[idx];

        delete src; // will not return
    }
    delete list;
    list = NULL;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem with above code is that the code will not return in `delete src`.

Without `delete src`, the code is executed to the end, but I think I should delete data_t assignments with `delete src`.

I would like to know the workaround for this, or some mistakes I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers you have stored in the `TList` were not allocated individually with `new`, so DO NOT try to `delete` them individually.  You need to instead `delete[]` the original array that you allocated with `new[]`:

```
struct data_t {
    int key;
    String name;
};

TList *list = NULL;
data_t *dataArray = NULL;

void __fastcall TForm1::addButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // add records
    list = new TList();
    dataArray = new data_t[2];

    dataArray[0].key = 31415;
    dataArray[0].name = L"pi";
    list->Add(&dataArray[0]);

    dataArray[1].key = 27182;
    dataArray[1].name = L"napier";
    list->Add(&dataArray[1]);

    ShowMessage(L"added");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::showButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // get records
    data_t *src;
    for(int idx=0; idx < list->Count; idx++) {
        src = (data_t*)list->Items[idx];
        String msg;
        msg = L"key:" + IntToStr(src->key) + " name:" + src->name;
        ShowMessage(msg);
    }

    // free
    delete list;
    list = NULL;

    delete[] dataArray;
    dataArray = NULL;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to `delete` the individual items, you have to `new` them individually:

```
struct data_t {
    int key;
    String name;
};

TList *list = NULL;

void __fastcall TForm1::addButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // add records
    list = new TList();

    data_t *item = new data_t;    
    item->key = 31415;
    item->name = L"pi";
    list->Add(item);

    item = new data_t;
    item->key = 27182;
    item->name = L"napier";
    list->Add(item);

    ShowMessage(L"added");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::showButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // get records
    data_t *src;
    for(int idx=0; idx < list->Count; idx++) {
        src = (data_t*)list->Items[idx];
        String msg;
        msg = L"key:" + IntToStr(src->key) + " name:" + src->name;
        ShowMessage(msg);
    }

    // free

    for(int idx=0; idx < list->Count; idx++) {
        src = (data_t*)list->Items[idx];
        delete src;
    }

    delete list;
    list = NULL;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `list` and `dataArray` should be class members, in case multiple instances of the form are made  (unlikely for a Form1, but still a good habit to have)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes. It helps a lot.

Comment: @ Matt McNabb: Thank you about the list and dataArray. I will include them as class members.